# how to get html element value from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html files :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.get( "target.html", function( data ) {
    var data = $(data);
var elem = $(data.find('#tst'));
console.log(elem);
});


});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p> This an p tag</p>

</body>
</html>
```

target.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p> This an p tag</p>
<h1 id="tst"> Test </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the value of $('#tst') from target.html to index.html . How do I achieve it ?

Both file are in the same base directory . Also the $("#tst") value will be static.

When i do console.log($(data)) i get this object

```
[text, script, text, script, text, p, text, h1#tst, text]
0: text
1: script
2: text
3: script
4: text
5: p
6: text
7: h1#tst
accessKey: ""align: ""attributes: NamedNodeMap0: idlength: 1__proto__: NamedNodeMapbaseURI: nullchildElementCount: 0childNodes: NodeList[1]children: HTMLCollection[0]classList: DOMTokenList[0]className: ""clientHeight: 0clientLeft: 0clientTop: 0clientWidth: 0contentEditable: "inherit"dataset: DOMStringMapdir: ""draggable: falsefirstChild: textfirstElementChild: nullhidden: falseid: "tst"innerHTML: " Test "innerText: " Test "isContentEditable: falselang: ""lastChild: textlastElementChild: nulllocalName: "h1"namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"nextElementSibling: nullnextSibling: textnodeName: "H1"nodeType: 1nodeValue: nulloffsetHeight: 0offsetLeft: 0offsetParent: nulloffsetTop: 0offsetWidth: 0onabort: nullonautocomplete: nullonautocompleteerror: nullonbeforecopy: nullonbeforecut: nullonbeforepaste: nullonblur: nulloncancel: nulloncanplay: nulloncanplaythrough: nullonchange: nullonclick: nullonclose: nulloncontextmenu: nulloncopy: nulloncuechange: nulloncut: nullondblclick: nullondrag: nullondragend: nullondragenter: nullondragleave: nullondragover: nullondragstart: nullondrop: nullondurationchange: nullonemptied: nullonended: nullonerror: nullonfocus: nulloninput: nulloninvalid: nullonkeydown: nullonkeypress: nullonkeyup: nullonload: nullonloadeddata: nullonloadedmetadata: nullonloadstart: nullonmousedown: nullonmouseenter: nullonmouseleave: nullonmousemove: nullonmouseout: nullonmouseover: nullonmouseup: nullonmousewheel: nullonpaste: nullonpause: nullonplay: nullonplaying: nullonprogress: nullonratechange: nullonreset: nullonresize: nullonscroll: nullonsearch: nullonseeked: nullonseeking: nullonselect: nullonselectstart: nullonshow: nullonstalled: nullonsubmit: nullonsuspend: nullontimeupdate: nullontoggle: nullonvolumechange: nullonwaiting: nullonwebkitfullscreenchange: nullonwebkitfullscreenerror: nullonwheel: nullouterHTML: "<h1 id="tst"> Test </h1>"outerText: " Test "ownerDocument: documentparentElement: nullparentNode: document-fragmentprefix: nullpreviousElementSibling: ppreviousSibling: textscrollHeight: 0scrollLeft: 0scrollTop: 0scrollWidth: 0shadowRoot: nullspellcheck: truestyle: CSSStyleDeclarationtabIndex: -1tagName: "H1"textContent: " Test "title: ""translate: truewebkitdropzone: ""__proto__: HTMLHeadingElement
8: textlength: 9__proto__: n[0]
```

When i do console.log(elem) i get this object

```
n.fn.init[0]
context: undefined
length: 0
selector: "#tst"
__proto__: n[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element

Try this:

```js
$.get("target.html", function(data) {
  var data = $(data);
  var elem = data.find('#tst');
});
```

**Edit:**

As all the `immediate` childs are returned by `$(data)`, `.find()` method is not applicable here as we do not have `parent` selector.

Create a `dummy` div and set `html` of this div as `data` so that we can use `DummyDiv.find()`

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("target.html", function(data) {
    var data = $('<div>', {
      html: data
    });
    var elem = data.find('#tst');
  });
});
```

Comment: How do i get the value 'Test' . I tried .val() and .html() it returns undefined.

Comment: This is what i tried . It returned undefined .
$.get( "target.html", function( data ) {
 var data = $(data);
   var elem = data.find('#tst');
 console.log(elem.html());
});

Comment: the html object of target.html

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Updated the question